# Embedding YouTube Videos at Time of Publish Instead of Time of Schedule (Bare URLS Make Me Sad)

Tags: youtube

If I'm adding a WP post and paste a URL for a public or unlisted YouTube video, the video appears normally embedded when the post is live (a standard YouTube player that the reader can click on and watch the video).

However, if the video is private *at the time a post is scheduled* and the video is later published *prior to the post going live*, only a bare URL is shown.

The scenario is scheduling both YT and WP content ahead of time.  If you schedule a YouTube video to go public Monday at 1pm, it's set to private.  If a Wordpress post embedding that video is scheduled and goes public at 2pm, it still shows a bare URL.  If you create the post fresh at 2pm, or if you go in and update the post at 2pm, the video is embedded as usual.

Is there a way to have Wordpress embed the video at time of publication instead of at time of scheduling?

Comment: There's no difference to WP from a post content point of view, generating an embed from a Youtube URL is a single task independent of where and how that URL came from, be it a post, or the status of that post, the result though is cached. This also means if you created a post using only the text view and never previewed it then it would never try to look up the embed HTML. So you might be better to look up how to flush the cache, or how quickly it expires